# Why are there two series representations of the natural logarithm?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

On the [Wikipedia article of the natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series) one finds two different series representations for $\ln(x)$:

- $\ln(x)= (x - 1) - \frac{(x-1) ^ 2}{2} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{3} - \frac{(x-1)^4}{4} \cdots$ for $x \in (0,2]$
- $\ln{x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1 \over {n}} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^n = \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right) + {1 \over 2} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^2 + {1 \over 3} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^3 + \cdots$ for $x \in [\tfrac 12,\infty)$

So on $x \in [\tfrac 12,2]$ one has

$$(x - 1) - \frac{(x-1) ^ 2}{2} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{3} \cdots = \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right) + {1 \over 2} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^2 + {1 \over 3} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^3 + \cdots$$

For $x \in (1,2)$ both series converge absolutely. So I thought, one can show the above equation for $x \in (1,2)$ by expanding the summands and reorder them. Unfortunately this does not seem to work. *First question:* Is there any easy way to show the equality of both series?

*Second question:* The right series also is

$$\left( {x - 1 \over x} \right) + {1 \over 2} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^2 + {1 \over 3} \left( {x - 1 \over x} \right)^3 + \cdots = \left( 1 - {1  \over x} \right) + {1 \over 2} \left( 1 - {1  \over x} \right)^2 + {1 \over 3} \left( 1 - {1  \over x} \right)^3$$

and is thus a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) after expanding all summands. The Laurent series does not seem to have any power $x^n$ with $n \ge 1$ (after expanding the summands there are just terms $\tfrac 1{x^n}$ with $n\ge 0$). How is it possible that such a sum leads to the equality with a Taylor series? The Taylor series does only have summands with the power $x^n$ ($n \ge 0$). Where do those summands come from?

Comment: One is an expansion in terms of ${1 \over x}$ and the other in terms of $x$. Note that $\log({1 \over x}) = - \log x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be:

Why are there to series representations of the natural logarithm expanded around x=0 ?

When in terms of (x-1) ,  (x-1) and powers vanish at x=1.

When in terms of x ,  - Infinity appears.